# Найти урожай и урожайность

Tags: c++

> В области 10 районов. Заданы площади, засеваемые пшеницей (в гектарах), и средняя урожайность (в центнерах гектара. в каждом районе. Определить количество пшеницы, собранное в области, и среднюю урожайность по области.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Осваивайте гугл, а вообще как-то так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] a = new int[10];
            int[] b = new int[10];

            int oblPl = 0, oblU = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ukazhite ploshad' " + i);
                a[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Ukazhite urozhai " + i);
                b[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                oblU = oblU + a[i] * b[i];
                oblPl = oblPl + a[i];
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Oblastnaya ploshad' " + oblPl);
            Console.WriteLine("Oblastnaya urozhainost' " + oblU/oblPl);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: нужна средняя урожайность, а не валовый сбор. oblU делим на 10

Comment: Ой, точно, упустил. Спасибо! Точнее даже не на 10, а на всю площадь.